# Ubuntu and AT&T Security

Tags: ubuntu, port-forwarding

I run a Minecraft server and Apache2 HTTPS server on my Ubuntu server. I have port forwarded those ports on my router to be opened to my Ubuntu machine. With the ports being opened, what can attackers do to my Ubuntu machine and other devices on the network?

Comment: This depends on what vulnerabilities exist on the system

Comment: And more specifically, what programs are listening on those ports on the Ubuntu machine.

Comment: 443: Apache2 25505: Minecraft